# Where does TeamCity place the build files?

Tags: teamcity

I am setting up TeamCity with a VS 2010 web solution and VSS.

I have it working and building automatically when someone checks in.

I am unable to find where the built bin folder is placed though.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Agent+Home+Directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Ales has given you the information in that link, your bin folder will be 'somewhere' under the build agents home directory, something like `c:\BuildAgent\work\?????` - the reason I use the question marks is from memory the directory name is not a constant and this may make it a bit harder to find if you want the files used for the build.

You can however override this behavior and tell TeamCity the checkout\build folder:

Edit the 'Version Control Settings' (step 2) of your build Configuration and change the checkout directory from auto to custom.

[image]

Before proceeding you should [read the docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Checkout+Directory#BuildCheckoutDirectory-Customcheckoutdirectory) regarding Custom path as there are some caveats

Comment: Ok thanks both of you, I shall check this out and get back to you.